# Removing duplicate items in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Can you help me for removing duplicate items in a list in python3 please ?
for example the input list is :
`['2001', '0', '3c4d', '15', '0', '0', 'db8', '1a2b']`

and output :
`['2001', '0', '3c4d', '15', 'db8', '1a2b']`

Comment: You can use set for.that

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. Please try your own research before asking a question. See [ask] for more tips.

Comment: `list(dict.from_keys(data))`

Answer (score 0):

```
OUTPUT = list(set(INPUT))
```

To preserve order:

```
OUTPUT = list(dict.fromkeys(INPUT)) # Credit to @Jab
```

Converts to a set of unique items, then back into list form.